# Android Emulator error in running simple project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I configure the Android emulator for version 4.4.2, the emulator just hangs and it does not get past the Android logo. when i checked the Console in Eclipse i get this error:
**ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query name in ''**

and this the screen shot of my Eclipse workbench:
[image]

and this the configuration of my Android Virual Device
[image]

**I'm a beginner in Android**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck the snapshot option then start the emulator, and if you are working on camera option then emulator does not support camera without giving hardware support while creating emulator.

Comment: As you seen in the screen shot of virtual device, the camera is not selected.
I disabled Snapshot option, but the Android logo not passed again!

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, Have you try genymotion ? It can enable camera on-the-fly and also faster.

Comment: @HERO, Could you say that which of [these](http://www.techbate.com/5-best-android-emulator-for-windows-87xp/) emulators are better and faster for Windows OS?

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, Bluestack and YouWave are good but they are not really dedicated for android development while genymotion is dedicated for development. And much easier and simpler because there is eclipse plug in for genymotion. Anyway, that's your choice.

Comment: @HERO, How can i use genymotion with Eclipse?

Comment: This is not a fix, the problem persists even after the suggested solution

Comment: the new version of Android Studio 1.3 RC 4 has same problem with this error : emulator: ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query name in '' and also the settings has set with : Snapshot: no - hw.camera.back: none

Comment: Like it has been said this is no fix. I am not even using snapshot feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to set front camera to emulated and back camera to none ...This worked for me..Hope it works for you.Here is the screenshot.
[check out the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsUnk.png)

Comment: check the above image link in my post

Answer (score 0):

I got [this error](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/358) when using both front and camera's emulated. However i think the profile is set to have only a back camera. so for me, only using the back camera worked. Though i didnt check that this was the root cause. It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error `ERROR: _factory_client_recv` and solved it by killing the server at command line with `adb kill-server`, then opening Android AVD Manager `android avd` and **deleting ALL of my Android Virtual Devices**, and creating a new AVD with these customisations (i.e. AVD Name: Nexus 4, Device: Android 4.4.2, Target: Intel Atom x86, Skin: No Skin, Front Camera: Webcam0, Internal Storage: 100MB, SD Card Size: 50MB, Emulator Options: Use Host GPU)