# Unable to start the Android emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I installed the Android SDK, set the AVD up and tried to launch the Emulator.

If launching the x86_64 machine, the emulator's display is blank (there's only skin).
If launching the x86 machine, I only have the android logo blinking without any progress.

Command line gives the log

```
$ ./emulator -avd Androidx86
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
emulator: ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query name in 'listZ'
emulator: ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query name in ''
Killed
```

The camera is disabled, though. The emulator fails to work no matter if there's snapshotting enabled or not, the same for the "Host GPU" option. So the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981922/android-emulator-error-in-running-simple-project) doesn't work.

Why does it refuse to work? I'm using Linux Mint 17 with MATE.

Comment: use bluestack or genymotion they are fast compared to avd

Comment: @Nilesh genymotion might face the same problem considering possible issue is HW related. OP, did emulator work for you on current machine ever before?

Comment: @poss: No, never. I've just set it up. Besides, does bluestack or genymotion work well with Qt5?